# How can I get Knockout.js to set the namespaceURI for attributes?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, svg

In an svg, if I use knockout to set the `xlink:href` attribute for an `a` node, the attribute's namespace isn't set correctly, so the `a` doesn't work as a link when clicked.

For example, consider the following svg that contains two linked ellipses.  One has its `xlink:href` attribute hardcoded, the other is set by knockout via the `data-bind` attribute:

```
<svg width="5cm" height="6cm" viewBox="0 0 5 6" version="1.1" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 
  <rect x=".01" y=".01" width="4.98" height="5.98"  
        fill="none" stroke="blue"  stroke-width=".03"/> 
  <a xlink:href="#hardcoded"> 
    <ellipse data-bind="attr: blue" /> 
  </a> 
  <a data-bind="attr: { 'xlink:href': href }"> 
    <ellipse data-bind="attr: red" /> 
  </a> 
</svg>
```

Getting knockout to run is pretty easy:

```
ko.applyBindings( { 
  blue: { cx:2.5, cy:1.5, rx:2, ry:1, fill:"blue" },
  href: '#foo', 
  red: { cx:2.5, cy:4.5, rx:2, ry:1, fill:"red" },
});
```

But only the link for the hardcoded one works.  If I add some code to view the `namespaceURI` value for the attribute node, I can see that
the `xlink:href` attribute set by knockout has a `null` namespaceURI, as opposed to the hardcoded one, which is set to `http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink`.

```
Array.forEach( document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function(a){
  a.setAttribute('title', 'xlink:href namespaceURI = ' + a.getAttributeNode('xlink:href').namespaceURI);
});
```

You can [view all this in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZghP7/).

Is there an easy way to tell knockout what the correct namespace should be for an attribute, or do I need to write a custom binding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My fallback solution is to add this custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers['attr-ns'] = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    ko.utils.objectForEach( ko.unwrap( valueAccessor() ), function(name, value){
      var prefixLen = name.indexOf(':');
      var prefix    = name.substr( 0, prefixLen );
      var namespace = prefixLen < 0 ? null : element.lookupNamespaceURI( prefix );

      element.setAttributeNS( namespace, name, ko.unwrap( value ) );
    });
  }
};
```

and change the template to use the `attr-ns` binding I defined:

```
<a data-bind="attr-ns: { 'xlink:href': href }">
  <ellipse data-bind="attr: red" />
</a>
```

This seems to work ok, but I'd rather not do this if I don't have to.  More custom code = more that could go wrong.

You can [view this solution in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XfJkJ/2/).

Comment: plus, specifying the namespace manually seems superfluous, especially given that it was specified just a few lines earlier as one of the svg attributes.  There should be a better solution that doesn't require the user to manually specify the namespace to cover that case.

Comment: I was about to write a replacement for the `attr` binding handler along those lines. No, there is no better way of specifying namespaced attributes than supplying the canonical namespace. Namespace prefixes do not exist for the DOM, they are a relevant for parsing only.

Comment: Tomalak: I think you can just use [`element.lookupNamespceURI`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-lookupNamespaceURI) to do the lookup for you.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to override [the default `attr` binding handler](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/attr.js) with a namespace-aware version.

FWIW, here is my take on it, use it as a transparent drop-in, it even supports namespace prefixes:

```
var attrHtmlToJavascriptMap = { 'class': 'className', 'for': 'htmlFor' },
    namespaceDecl = {
        svg: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        xlink: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    };

ko.bindingHandlers['attr'] = {
    'update': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};
        ko.utils.objectForEach(value, function(attrName, attrValue) {
            var attrRawValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(attrValue),
                toRemove = (attrRawValue === false) || (attrRawValue === null) || (attrRawValue === undefined),
                attrStrValue = attrRawValue.toString(),
                attrNameParts = attrName.split(":"),
                attrNsUri = (attrNameParts.length === 2) ? namespaceDecl[attrNameParts[0]] : null,
                attrName = (attrNsUri) ? attrNameParts[1] : attrNameParts[0];

            if (toRemove) {
                if (attrNsUri) {
                    element.removeAttributeNS(attrNsUri, attrName);
                } else {
                    element.removeAttribute(attrName);
                }
            }

            if (ko.utils.ieVersion <= 8 && attrName in attrHtmlToJavascriptMap && !attrNsUri) {
                attrName = attrHtmlToJavascriptMap[attrName];
                if (toRemove)
                    element.removeAttribute(attrName);
                else
                    element[attrName] = attrValue;
            } else if (!toRemove) {
                if (attrNsUri) {
                    element.setAttributeNS(attrNsUri, attrName, attrStrValue);
                } else {
                    element.setAttribute(attrName, attrStrValue);
                }
            }

            if (attrName === "name") {
                ko.utils.setElementName(element, toRemove ? "" : attrValue.toString());
            }
        });
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZghP7/1/

Comment: Yeah, if I have to wrap this up in a plugin, I'll definitely take your approach of basing `attr-ns` on the existing code as much as possible.

Comment: You inspired me to [create a pull request to update the default `attr` binding to support namespaces](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1066)

Comment: @rampion Very nice code, if it actually works (compatibility issues might crop up). A useful proposal in any case.

Comment: @rampion Oh, and while we are at it, can you explain [this line](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1066/files#L0R25) to me?

Comment: That was me, trying and failing, to make my selection of the `<a>` element more clear. I put a comment in the commit.

Comment: Good point about compatibility. I guess getting some folks to test it on different browsers would help get it merged in faster.