# how call function when dynamically data changed in svg element using knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, svg

I'm using knockout-2.2.1.js in my application and i'm also using svg elements too. I'm using knockout for updating the svg elements attribute when data is changed.

```
<rect  data-bind=\'attr: { transform : viewModel.data()>0? "rotate(180 {{html xValueConverter("x")}} {{html yValueConverter()}})" : "rotate(180 0 0)",  height: viewModel.data()<0 ? 0 :viewModel.data() }\' width="20" fill="#38ACEC"></rect>
```

In the above code knockout is working fine for `height` but it is not working for attribute `transform`. The xValueConverter("x") and yValueConverter() is called at only on it creation.

How can i call the method again when the data is changed and Is there any other way to call those methods by knockout?.

Any suggestions should be appreciated!.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083723/how-can-i-get-knockout-js-to-set-the-namespaceuri-for-attributes

Comment: It looks like you are using Knockout wrong. You should not do any calculations in the bindings, that's what the view model is for. If you show more of your view model and handlebars (?) template, I'll try to suggest a nicer way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use computed observables to calculate the rotation, like this (fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6f4X3/6/ ) :

html:

```
height: <input type="text" data-bind="value:actualData, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" /><br />
rotationAngle: <input type="text" data-bind="value:rotationAngle, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" /><br />
rotationPointX: <input type="text" data-bind="value:rotationPointX, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" /><br />
rotationPointY: <input type="text" data-bind="value:rotationPointY, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" /><br />

<svg>
    <rect data-bind='attr:{ transform:rotation, height:data() < 0 ? 0 : data()}'
    width="20" x="70" y="40" fill="#38ACEC"></rect>
</svg>
```

js:

```
var VM = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.actualData = ko.observable(100);
    self.data = ko.computed(function(){
        return parseInt(self.actualData(), 10);
    }, self);

    self.rotationAngle = ko.observable(20);
    self.rotationPointX = ko.observable(10);
    self.rotationPointY = ko.observable(10);

    self.rotation = ko.computed(function(){
        if (self.data() <= 0) {
            return "rotate(180 0 0)";
        } else {
            var r = "rotate(" + self.rotationAngle() + " " + self.rotationPointX() + " " + self.rotationPointY() +")";
            console.log(r);
            return r;
        }
    }, self);
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```